# a bit of issue I'm running into

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is this:
Find the lastname and firstname of members who have borrowed both books titled “XML and XQuery” and “XQuery: The XML Query Language” either currently or in the past.

For my query, its supposed to print out "David Jones" only since both the book title is in CurrentLoan and in History but instead its printing out three other member also. Am I doing something wrong with my query?

Here is the data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fe0b/1

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
    (bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (30),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID));  

CREATE TABLE Member
    (memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID));

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
    (memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

CREATE TABLE History
    (memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery', 'Author Le', 2017, 'non-fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Yellow Bird', 'Jake Red', 2014, 'reference');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'XQuery: The XML Query Language', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (21, 1212121212, 'The Giving Tree', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (22, 2121212121, 'Gone Fishing', 'Shel Silverstein', 1964, 'reference');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (23, 1313131313, 'The Lazy Dog', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (24, 3131313131, 'The Red Bird', 'Jake Red', 2016, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO BOOK VALUES (25, 1414141414, 'The Very Blue Boy', 'Ben Jen', 2006, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 10);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 8);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 9);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 3);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (006, 'Khang', 'Nkaujyi', '358 Spencer', 2145345625, 5);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (007, 'Jones', 'David', '4th Street', 14812365789, 10);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (002, 25, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (001, 20, '13-JAN-17', '15-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (006, 14, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (003, 15, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (007, 17, '02-OCT-17', '25-DEC-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 17, '14-Jan-17', '04-JUN-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (003, 19, '12-Jan-17', '04-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (001, 13, '14-APR-17', '08-OCT-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (006, 20, '14-MAY-17', '04-DEC-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (007, 20, '02-OCT-16', '25-DEC-16');
COMMIT;
```

My query:

```
SELECT lastname, firstname
FROM Member
INNER JOIN CurrentLoan ON Member.memberID = CurrentLoan.memberID
INNER JOIN Book ON CurrentLoan.bookID = Book.bookID
WHERE Book.title = 'XML and XQuery' or title = 'XQuery: The XML Query Language'
UNION
SELECT lastname, firstname
FROM Member
INNER JOIN History ON Member.memberID = History.memberID
INNER JOIN Book ON History.bookID = Book.bookID
WHERE Book.title = 'XML and XQuery' or title = 'XQuery: The XML Query Language';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of hurdles to answer this question.  First, we need to deal with the requirement of a member either currently borrowing a book, or having borrowed it in the past.  You have two tables, `CurrentLoan` and `History`, whose structures are almost identical.  For the purposes of your query, we really only care about the `memberID` and the `bookID`.  One way to consolidate them is to just use a union between these two tables.  This makes sense, because if a member turns up with a book in either table, we want to count it.

With that out of the way, we can now aggregate over your tables by member, and check for members who have used both of the titles of interest.  In the `t2` subquery below we find such matching `memberID`.  Then, all that is needed is one more join back to the `Member` table to retrieve the full record for each matching member.

```
SELECT
    t1.firstname,
    t1.lastname
FROM Member t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.memberID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT memberID, bookID
        FROM CurrentLoan
        UNION ALL
        SELECT memberID, bookID
        FROM History
    ) t
    INNER JOIN Member m
        ON t.memberID = m.memberID
    INNER JOIN Book b
        ON t.bookID = b.bookID
    WHERE
        b.title IN ('XML and XQuery', 'XQuery: The XML Query Language')
    GROUP BY t.memberID
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT b.title) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.memberID = t2.memberID
```

This outputs David Jones only, as you expected.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I only need the lastname and firstname from member.